# How to push an object to Array in Mongo using Node driver

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am learning MongoDB and Node and trying to make a crud application without any ORM such as Mongoose.

I am facing an issue inserting an object to an array which is part of a document.

Basically I want to add an "order" to the orders attribute of "product" document each time a user buys a product. 
    console.log(req.session.cartitems);
    console.log(req.session.cartqty);

```
for(item in req.session.cartitems)
    {
        console.log(req.session.cartitems[item]);

        var orderedItem = req.session.cartitems[item];
        mongo.connect(mongoURL, function(){
        console.log('Connected to mongo at: ' + mongoURL);
        var coll = mongo.collection('products');

        coll.update({_id:orderedItem._id},{
            $push: {
                orders: {
                        buyer: req.session.username,
                        quantity:orderedItem.item_quantity
                        }
                  }
        });
    });
}
```

but the update operation is not doing anything.

Here is a sample object inside Mongo that I am trying to push to:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5810a2b01ef60d0cdcc6e80c"),
"product_id" : 1,
"item_name" : "FitBit Charge 2",
"item_description" : "Charge HR + PurePulse Monitor",
"seller_name" : "ak@gmail.com",
"item_price" : "150",
"item_quantity" : "10",
"sale_type" : "sale",
"posted_at" : "2016:10:26 05:33:52",
"expires_at" : "2016:10:30 05:33:52",
"bids" : [],
"orders" : []
```

}

Comment: do you get any error if you add a callback function? maybe you have a matching problem, did you try just to do `find` by the id to see if you get any results?

Comment: I did get an error saying "MongoReferrence Error: Atleast one of update or remove must be defined".